# How should we communicate with docker containers when I am trying to make multiple containers?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerode

Below steps I want to do using dockerode.

1. Create container on request
2. Compile code inside container
3. Extract output from container
4. Finally delete container

I have api/run endpoint(next.js) inside docker container.
To this endpoint I want send code as input and want to capture output from that container

Below is my code where,
I am creating new container and when that container starts.
I want to make axios post request to the api/run endpoint running inside container to send input.
After process I want to capture the output or the response from request made.

I was trying to use IPaddress where container is running. But I found that we can't access container using IP.

Then what is the way to do this?

```
 const data = await request.json();
    const { language, program, inputs } = data;
    const docker = new Docker();
    const containerId = v4();
    // 1. I am trying to spin new container using dockerode on each request
    const container = await docker.createContainer({
      Image: "project-name",
      name: containerId,
    });
    await container.start();
    const containerInfo = await container.inspect();
    const ipAddress = containerInfo.NetworkSettings.IPAddress;
    const containerUrl = `http://${ipAdress}/api/run`;
    // 2 .Send code as input to that container's api/run endpoint (Where compiler logic is)

    const response = await axios.post(containerUrl, data);
    // 3. Then stop and remove after getting output
    await container.stop();
    await container.remove();
```

Comment: It could be a timing issue where the container doesn't have time to get ready before you send the request. What errors do you get?

Comment: This is not the issue I can see container running in my docker desktop but axios requests  to api/run doesn't give any response the request gets timed out after certain time.

Comment: The container-private IP address isn't useful; there's only one host environment where it's possible to reach it.  Your container needs to publish ports and you need to talk to those published ports.

Comment: Also consider that, while you're getting a little bit of protection by running the user-provided code in a container, you're trading that off for the driver process gaining unrestricted root-level permission over the entire host, and there are still unpleasant things the untrusted code can do (would it be more profitable to just run a cryptocurrency miner yourself, instead of on your end users' behalf)?

Comment: Why is this tagged with `amazon-ecs`? You aren't using Amazon ECS in your question, and indeed it would be impossible to use Amazon ECS for this specific purpose.